# Adipoli jQuery Image Hover Effects don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, hover, adipoli

I have a problem with adipoli plugin - it doesn't want to work though everything I have done seems to be correct. The code is as follows:

head section:

```
    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/lightbox.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.adipoli.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.shadow').adipoli({
    'startEffect' : 'normal',
    'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
});
</script>
```

content section:

```
echo '"<a><img class="shadow" src="photos/thumbs/thumb_'.$image['filename'].'" alt="" /></a>';
```

Along with adipoli hover effect, I want to make a simple css drop shadow effect and it works in comparison to hover effect. Lightbox and slider script work perfectly as well.
Any useful ideas would be appreciated, especially useful ones. ;-)

Comment: Does the image element aready exist, when you select it? Is f.e. `console.log( $('.shadow').attr('src') );` returning anything?

Comment: Oh, did not know that it has to exist before selecting it. I don't know js and it was not written on the Adipoli site. I added it to the end of site and it works! Edward, I thank you very, very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shadow').adipoli({
        'startEffect' : 'normal',
        'hoverEffect' : 'popout'
    });
});
```

Wrap it like this to make sure the element exists before you try selecting it.